# Getting the value of a ModelForm's field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Would any of you be able to tell me how I can get the data/value of a model-form's fields? I know how to get the initial data but if I've understood correctly, a form's fields also have a data/value value associated with it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about after a user submits a form?

Comment: A form only has it's initial value or it's related db value (fi NULL) before someone submits it.. (well except for clientside scripting, javascript etc), so I suppose you mean after it's submitted.. which is just form.field.value()...?

Comment: HI ArgsKwargs, I managed to do it using your answer. This worked `form['fieldsname'].value()`. Thanks

Comment: you should be using cleaned_data as that's the python representation of the object (casts to an integer for forms.IntegerField for example) see my answer and the docs below

Answer (score 5):

You use cleaned_data https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form
Here's an example:

```
>> models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=140)

>> forms.py
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

>> views.py

def book_update(request):
    form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print form.cleaned_data['author']
```